# The first time animating UIScrollView contentOffset is not animated

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uikit, core-animation

I have a UIScrollView (self.zoomScrollView) with another UIView (self.pageView) in it. I'm animating the zoomScale and contentOffset using

```
CGPoint p1 = [tap locationInView:self.pageView];
CGPoint p2 = CGPointMake(p1.x * 3, p1.y * 3);
CGPoint d  = CGPointMake(p2.x - p1.x, p2.y - p1.y);
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                 animations:^{
                     [self zoomScrollView].zoomScale = 3;
                     [self.zoomScrollView setContentOffset:d animated:NO];
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                 }];
```

The first time this animation runs the contentOffset is set to its final value immediately and then the zoomScale is animated up to meet it. Every other time after that this animation works perfectly. Any ideas on why it doesn't work the first time?

Answer (score 0):

The `zoomScale` and `contentOffset` properties are not animatable, so changing them inside a `UView` animation block does nothing. To animate `contentOffset`, just pass `YES` to `setContentOffset:animated:` without using an animation block. Likewise for `zoomScale` (check the docs).

Animatable properties:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/animatingviews/animatingviews.html

UIScrollView:
[https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIScrollView/setZoomScale:animated](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIScrollView/setZoomScale%3aanimated):

Comment: Hmmm, do you mean that they are not animatable "together"? Or that there's "unexpected behavior" when animating them? It seems zoomScale animates just fine, as well as contentOffset after the first go.

Comment: That said, I have tried calling setZoomScale:animated: and setContentOffset:animated: but firing both at the same time causes them to compete for the contentOffset yielding unexpected results (that look much worse than the solution above).